# Heroku Rails 3 app crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, deployment

Just deployed the latest version of a simple Rails 3 app to Heroku and it keeps crashing when I try to start it. The error seems to some how be connected to the "Thin" gem or the "heroku[router]:" portion of the logs. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

```
2014-02-05T06:24:38.338411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-05T12:04:16.669527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-05T12:04:20.601552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle 
exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 40314`
2014-02-05T12:04:21.913325+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2014-02-05T12:04:21.913325+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with 
`bundle install`
2014-02-05T12:04:23.263777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-05T12:04:23.276036+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-05T17:50:56.718434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-05T17:51:01.055269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle 
exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 6172`
2014-02-05T17:51:02.712737+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing
gem executables with `bundle install`
2014-02-05T17:51:02.712496+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2014-02-05T17:51:04.133893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-02-05T17:51:04.150001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-05T22:43:04.240693+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"  
method=GET path=/ host=treebook285.herokuapp.com request_id=6ed7479c-573e-4057- 
a2aa-d62bcb6078de fwd="76.175.73.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-05T23:24:56.285710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Gemfile has `gem 'thin'` in it and your Procfile should look something like this

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```